# Nativescript custom angular component template manipulation in AbsoluteLayout

Tags: nativescript, angular-components, nativescript-angular

Lets say I've created a custom component and want to place it inside `AbsoluteLayout` of parent component. So basically I would do something like this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
   <custom-component></custom-component>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

But what if I want to adjust a position of the custom component and use `AbsoluteLayout`'s `top` and `left` attributes on the child? The problem is that I can't put this attributes directly on custom child tag. The only solution I found is to wrap custom component with `StackLayout`:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout top="50">
       <custom-component></custom-component>
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

So my question is how can I position custom child without adding additional wrapper layout and make code like below work:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
       <custom-component top="50"></custom-component>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Should I make any changes to my child component? Or maybe it's not possible to get rid of wrapper layout at all?

Comment: You will have to use `@Input` for `top` and `left` inside `custom-component` and bind those values to the root element.

Comment: @Manoj thank you for your response! This option was quite a surprise for me since I thought that ns angular wraps a content of the child component with a <child_component_name_tag> in a same way as it does in a dom. So that root container inside the custom component is not a direct child of AbsoluteLayout and top attribute would be ignored. Wouldn't it?